# I need a REGEX to validate a password field

Tags: regex

The password must have between 6-15 character and cannot allow the & and %.

Comment: What’s wrong with `&` or `%`?

Comment: If its a password field why at you stopping the user use those characters? Most people use the same password for websites...(although they shouldnt). Limiting them to what they can have in their password makes it feel less secure. Its a password for a reason.

Comment: Is this password supposed to be used in an [application/x-www-form-urlencoded encoded format](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1)? Otherwise I don’t see a reason why you would want to disallow these characters.

Comment: Sometimes some characters conflict with databases. I don't think the question deserves to be downvoted on the principle of whether or not those characters aren't allowed. Even with just standard letters and numbers, the number of permutations is massive.

Answer (score 9):

```
/^[^&%]{6,15}$/
```

Comment: Great, simple answer. And if you want an explanation. The `^` inside the `[^&%]` essentially means `NOT` so you're allowing any character except those two, 6 – 15 times. One note: if those two characters will cause problems, I wonder what other characters will... there are LOTS of characters out there in Unicode-land.